# How do i send the user to another local page in a form with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm currently working on a school project and i need to make a form for my webapp. i want a form to direct the user to another local page if you click the button. i tried several things but it didn't work out. My Webapp is using Jquery mobile and is a multipage website. how do i do this? here is my code:

```html
    <div id="pag16" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#producten" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">P</a>
    <a href="#boodschappenlijst" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">B</a>
    <h1>Swynth's Webapp</h1>
   </div>
   <div  role="main" class="ui-content">
    <br>
   <div class="ui-body ui-body-b ui-corner-all sizing">
    <p>Got a question, awesome idea or business inquiries? Leave your message down below! thanks!</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="hobby">Choose your type of message</label>
     <select name="hobby" id="hobby" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
      <option value="">Choose type of message:</option>
      <option value="1">Feedback</option>
      <option value="2">Awesome idea(s)</option>
      <option value="3">Business Inquiries</option>
      <option value="4">Bug report(s)</option>
      <option value="5">Other</option>
     </select>
     <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="naam">Your Name:</label>
     <input name="naam" id="naam" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value="" data-mini="true" required>
     <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="opmerkingen">Message:</label>
     <textarea name="opmerkingen" id="opmerkingen" placeholder="Your message" rows="8" cols="40" data-mini="true"></textarea>
     <p>What do you think about the Swynth Webapp?
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
      <label for="y">Cool!</label>
      <input name="option" id="y" type="radio" checked="checked" value="y">
      <label for="n">Could be better (leave a message what to improve)</label>
      <input name="option" id="n" type="radio" value="n">
     </fieldset>
     <br>
     <label for="beoordeling">On a scale from 1 to 10, How do you rate my music?</label>
     <input name="beoordeling" id="beoordeling" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="10" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true">
     <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="verzend">Send Message</label>
     <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini" id="verzend" type="submit">Send Message</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h3>&copy; Swynth</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, if it's a single-page website, what page are you redirecting to?

Comment: Oh sorry its supposed to be multipage, sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Mobile - Submit a form, redirect to a page id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478240/jquery-mobile-submit-a-form-redirect-to-a-page-id)

Comment: yes it does, thank you!

Comment: If understood correctly, you are trying to redirect the user to another local page through your form (by clicking Send Message button). If that's the case, you should make sure to add your new url at your form action attribute (leaving it blank, means its gonna redirect you to the same page you're currently at, after you submit it)